# How to wait until file copy from system directory to external storage with root access

Tags: java, android, root, android-file

i have file from next path: `/data/data/com.google.chrome/examplefile.txt`, and i wanna copy the file by path: `/sdcard/examplefile.txt` and perform operations with him, but file size: 7 MB, and it takes time. I wanna copy the file wait until him copies and perform operations with him.

I have superuser access (Root), and to copy file from /data/data dir need root access.

Comment: ...and you want what? sorry for my question, but it's really unclear what do you want.

Comment: how to wait util copy file

Answer (score 0):

Use an AsyncTask to do the job on background:

```
public class CopyFileTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    File file;

    public CopyFileTask () {
        file = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //Your code to copy the file here
        file = copyFileMethod();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //If the file is not null, then that means you copied it
        if(file != null ){
        //Perform here the rest of the operations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how i wait until proccess end?

Comment: The process run in the background, and it starts the onPostExecute() method once it finishes. If you want to show a progress view I'll edit my response to show you how.

Comment: i wanna say, how async task will know is file copied?

Comment: @k1ceargy edited my response to show you how. It works in a background thread, so once it finishes just check if the file is not null.